# Is there a equivalent of "js ...array decomposition" for php?

Tags: php, arrays, decomposition

```
function f(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
f(...args); // <= Like this
```

Is there a equivalent of "js `...array` decomposition" for php?

(PS: I have already search on google with keyword like : "php array decomposition" but no luck)

Comment: it is called "spreading operator" and it is available starting PHP 7.4: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

Comment: @CornelRaiu > Exactly what i want, but i want use it on php5.6 so it's impossible, thanks!

Comment: you should think about upgrading your app to PHP 7+. It is better in every possible way than PHP 5.6

Comment: check my answer, there might be a solution for what you are trying to achieve on PHP 5.6

Comment: You really should not be using PHP < 7. Upgrade your PHP ASAP.

Comment: The php version I used here is a contraint for a project.

Answer (score 1):

It is called **spread operator** and it is available starting PHP 7.4

You can find more details about it [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array).

However, what you are doing here: `f(...args)` can be achieved using the **Splat Operator** which was introduced in PHP 5.6.
You can see more details [here](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator)

Comment: For Spread Operator for php7.4, yes exactly what i search.
But for Splat Operator for older version, it does not do the same thing, it doesn't respond to the question